# Compare 2 SQL tables, if data does not match, put an integer value in 3rd table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to compare 3 sql tables (A, B, C)? Which A and B have columns labled Name, TimeStamp in A, and Name, ScheduledTime in B. I need to compare these 2 columns and if they do not match up, put a numeric value of 1 into column 2 next to the name in table C. I'm fairly new to SQL but wasn't sure if this was possible. (Using SSMS)

Table A looks like this.

```
Name   |   Time                           
-----------------
John   |   7:00AM
Joe    |   7:07AM
Tim    |   7:25AM
```

Table B looks like this.

```
Name   |   Schedule
--------------------
John   |   7:00AM
Joe    |   7:00AM
Tim    |   7:00AM
```

Table C should look like this.

```
Name   |   Number
-----------------
John   |   0
Joe    |   1
Tim    |   1
```

Comment: Please depict your table structures, input data and expected output as well as what SQL you have tried so far..

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Think through the scenarios more clearly:  What happens if there are rows in one table but not the other?  What if the timestamps are off by one second?  Does Table C being updated or are new rows being inserted?

Comment: If names appear in table A that are not in Table B, I want it to just "skip" that line and move on to the next data. Timestamps should be recorded by minutes only (its not in depth into seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your sample data, the following will work:

```
select a.name, (case when a.time = b.schedule then 0 else 1 end) as number
into c
from a join
     b
     on a.name = b.name;
```

It is not clear if that is a general solution, but it works for the provided data.

EDIT:

SQL Fiddle does not seem to be running MS SQL code right now.  But [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/610ba) is a SQL Fiddle that I'm confident will show that the above works.

Comment: Works perfectly and exactly as needed. I will need to ask more SQL questions but I will open as separate questions for them. Thanks Gordon.

Comment: I might have cut a little too quick on this, it creates the table and columns as needed and says it's successful but the data is never generated. No names or 0's or 1's in the columns.

Comment: If SELECT...INTO isn't a good fit for your usage, the same query could be used in a CREATE VIEW or INSERT statement (depending on whether you want automatic updates or not)