# SQL query JOIN is greyed out and 3rd table is blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT a.NAME
    ,(CASE 
            WHEN a.TIME = b.schedule
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
      END ) AS number
INTO C
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
    ON a.NAME = b.NAME;
```

It creates the 3rd table as needed but the table is empty and I assure you the time column from A does not match all of schedule column from B.

I noticed the JOIN is greyed out which I have reason to believe is what is causing the issue, but is there anything I missed for this query to function as needed? Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If `C` is empty, then no rows match the `join` condition; the names are not the same.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?  Assuming the name field matches in both tables, your query looks ok to me.

Comment: You can just remove the `INTO c` row and see if the query returns any results, because that is what will go into the `c` table. You can continue adjusting from there and when you get the `SELECT` with the data that you want to be put into c, then just add back `INTO c`.

Comment: In default SSMS colour scheme, `JOIN` is always grey, doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Gordon! Good to see you again, I do have names that are listed in A but not B however there are infact names in A that are in B. Is this a problem? - also, thank you HoneyBadger, was beginning to think it was something wrong with just me and my SSMS software.

Comment: Sample data can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536058/compare-2-sql-tables-if-data-does-not-match-put-an-integer-value-in-3rd-table
Was a previous question I had asked in December.

Comment: @Sam And isn't that the answer you're looking for now? Since Gordon already answered your question in December...

Comment: `Join` isn't the problem. Probably your datatypes don't match between `time` and `schedule`. Check that first.

Comment: In that case, your `name` columns aren't matching. You might need to trim.

Comment: actually what you provided with the "LEFT JOIN" recommendation - the data started to populate. His did indeed answer the question but I'm afraid I did not confirm the data that is populated as I had mixed up the query he provided versus the one I had input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in your comment that the query works with a `left join`. That means that your `a.Name = b.Name` condition is failing when you try to do an `inner join`.

In this case, you'll need to figure out why they don't match each other appropriately, if there is a leading space for instance.

Based on your comment, your columns don't match, so you'll need to do some creative querying to get what you want (assuming you can't fix the data). It's ugly and not a great way to do it but you could try matching on just the beginning of the field, up to the semi-colon:

```
SELECT a.NAME
,(CASE 
        WHEN a.TIME = b.schedule
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
  END ) AS number
 INTO C
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
 on substring(a.Name,1,CHARINDEX(';',a.Name)) = substring(b.Name,1,CHARINDEX(';',b.Name))
```

Comment: The datatype won't matter, `John            ` = `John`, only if a name starts with a space it would matter. And `John` in `(n)varchar(12)` is the same as `John` in `(n)varchar(25)`

Comment: `John` != `john`. Caps matter.

Comment: That was a typo, thanks. And even caps don't have to matter, that depends on collation

Comment: @HoneyBadger You're right. I got stuck on the thought about time and schedule not matching types because that is so common. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I did notice in my name columns in both tables are not exactly the same. The formatting is a little off. A has lastname/first;initials and B has lastname/first;office. I'm begining to think that his is the cause given the data you all have provided.

Comment: @Sam yeah, so those aren't going to match.

Comment: Copy that, thank you guys. I can manage the data to make them match. Super appreciate all the help from everyone.